# How to hunt memory leaks in webapp?

Tags: java, sqlite, tomcat, jsf, primefaces

I have big problem with memory leaks in my web app. Application runs out of memory after about 7h when being used by few people.

This is how my app works:

- user lands on login page, logs in, on succesfull login User POJO object is added to session map as follows:
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", user);
- on each subsequent page request, AuthFilter checks if there's "user" object in session map and allows further access;
- I have SessionScoped bean (LoggedUserBean) that holds user information (along with privileges, initialized upon login) because it is accessed very frequently. LoggedUserBean is injected in most beans and it is also accessed directly from XHTML pages.
- There are also few other SessionScoped beans that should hold their state. Most beans have injected DAO objects (@Named, default @Dependent). Very few beans and all DAO object have injected DatabaseConnection object (@Named with datasource created in constructor as follows:
  `dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/" + "jdbc/MyResName");`).
- there are few (@Named) validators for Primefaces Dialogs that validate dynamically created component trees:

`<h:inputHidden value="true">
    <f:validator binding="#{someValidator}"/>
 </h:inputHidden>`

and implementation is something like this:

```
@Named
public class SomeValidator extends ValidatorCommon implements Validator {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SomeValidator.class);

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) throws ValidatorException {...}
{...}
```

This is my context.xml:

```
<Resource auth="Container"
          driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC"
          maxTotal="1"
          maxIdle="1"
          minIdle="1"
          maxWaitMillis="5000"
          initialSize="1"
          name="jdbc/MyResName"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="5"
          logAbandoned="true"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          url="jdbc:sqlite:path/to/db/db.db">
</Resource>
```

I've created heap dump with VisualVM and MAT shows this leak suspect (https://i.stack.imgur.com/J03Xi.png): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J03Xi.png]

As far as I understand, RequestScoped bean is created each time it is requested/accessed, while SessionScoped is retrieved from container for particular session (or is created if it does not exist) so even if there are cross-references between my beans, this all should work just fine.

This is where I actually need help: how to analyze where those leaks come from? There's definitely something that does not allow memory to be released, but how can I find it?

I'm using Primefaces 6.0, Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.3 (7.0.1), JDK 1.7.0_80-b15, Mojarra 2.2.6, sqlite-jdbc 3.14.2.1.

If any additional files are necessary, please let me know and I'll edit this post to add them.

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/MyResName</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/pub/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Error pages -->
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/pages/pub/err/expired.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <!-- Prevents comments in xhtml pages to be placed in final html and evaluated -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Primefaces theme -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>forceUTF8CharSet</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>forceUTF8CharSet</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ttf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-sfnt</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff2</extension>
        <mime-type>application/font-woff2</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot?#iefix</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#latobold</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#latoblack</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
        <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#latolight</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#latoregular</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg#fontawesomeregular</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my issue.

My problem was not in any of my beans, handler, validators, auth mechanisms etc. Real problem was that I included two libs in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't quite know how does TomEE behave when it encounters two separate implementations (TomEE's own and above), but it seems that something prevented releasing references to some resources which caused WebContext to always grow in size (it was holding all objects that participated in request handling - across multiple pages). Or maybe this is a bug in jsf implementation?

If someone could explain what actually happend then I'd accept such answer as solution to my problem. Until then, this answer (without much reasoning) is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe start by giving a try to TomEE 7.0.2. If it doesn't help then try to debug WebContext map to check which CDI beans are not released, then you will be able to know who (tomee, tomcat, primefaces, other) is responsible of it and check if you can fix it.

Comment: I'll try with newer TomEE first.
It also suprises me that I didn't think about debugging Tomcat... I'll give it a go and will be back to you in ~8h.